# Sort stdClass Object after an array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sorting

I have two arrays,

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => art
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => adsdf
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => adsdf
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 7
            [title] => adsdf
        )

)
Array
(
    [2] => 2
    [1] => 1
)
```

And I want to sort the first array after the second array. In the second array the key and the value is equal with the first array id. So the output have to be the following.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => adsdf
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => art
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => adsdf
        )
    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 7
            [title] => adsdf
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`array_multisort`<sup>*[Docs]*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) for it:

```
array_multisort($arraySort, $arrayData);
```

Pass the array with the sort order as the first and your array to be sorted as the second parameter.

You might need to build the sort array prior to it, from your question it's not clear to me if you already have it or not.

In case not, if you want to get all of the data arrays entries ID values into the sort array:

```
$arraySort = array();
foreach($arrayData as $key => $obj)
{
    $arraySort[$key] = $obj->id;
}
```